# Subscribe to Tour of Hero's Search bar results in different component

Tags: typescript, angular2-services

I am new to Angular 4 (I have previous experience with AngularJS) and I am attempting to wrap my brain around Observables.

I am following the [Tour of Heroe's HTTP](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) portion of the tutorial where they walk you through creating a search bar.

I have completed this successfully and have results populating in a mat-autocomplete (not in the tutorial I added this part on my own) drop down of my search bar via the simulated http.get in the service.

In an attempt to see if I understand observable's or not, I created a component called **sidenav.component.ts** and it is a child component of the **app.component.html** template.

- **sidenav.component.html** is just boiler plate code from the  [Material Sidenav Example](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview)

I am attempting to put a simple for loop in a div in the **sidenav.component.html** component to see if I can pipe the output of that search bar into a different component template.

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heros | async"></div>
```

- I have registered the **HeroSearchService** as a provider at the **app.module.ts** level

and I am injecting that service into my **sidenav.component.ts**  as follows

```
constructor( private heroSearchService: HeroSearchService) {}
```

***but this is where I get confused... and my question is this.***

- If I wanted to register to the data that is populating my mat-autocomplete below my search bar, would I subscribe to the **search()** method in the **HeroSearchService**?

so you don't have to go review the code in the tutorial the service code is as follows. (with one minor change on my part, I set term to NULL to make it optional)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http }       from '@angular/http';

import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Hero }           from './hero';

@Injectable()
export class HeroSearchService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  search(term: string **= null**): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http
               .get(`api/heroes/?name=${term}`)
               .map(response => response.json().data as Hero[]);
  }
}
```

I have attempted the following in my "sidenav" component expecting to see the output of my mat-autocomplete also output in the console.log... but it does not seem to work.

```
    heroes: Observable<Hero[]>;

    constructor( private heroSearchService: HeroSearchService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.heroes = this.heroSearchService.search()

        this.hospitals.subscribe(
        value => console.log(value)
     ) 
 }
```

Hoping someone can help me understand how to update both components with the output of the **search()** method in the **HeroSearchService**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're not understanding how that works.

Every time you type something in your search bar, the autocomplete calls your search service **with the typed value as argument**, obtains a new Observable returned by the service, and subscribes to this observable to display the suggestions.

What you're doing in your component is simply to call the service when your component is initialized, with nothing as argument (which makes little sense: you're asking for all the suggestions without even a search term), and thus obain an Observable, different from all the observables returned to the search bar when you enter something in it, and display the suggestions returned for this absence of search term.

To do what you want to achieve (i.e. display the suggestions obtained by the search bar every time it gets some, after typing some text), you would need to expose an observable in your service, that would emit all the search results returned to the search bar. Something like that:

```
export class HeroSearchService {

  searchResults = new Subject<Hero[]>();

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  search(term: string **= null**): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http
               .get(`api/heroes/?name=${term}`)
               .map(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
               .do(heroes => this.searchResults.next(heroes));
  }
}
```

So, to explain, you would wiretap into the communication between the search bar and the service and emit all the search results returned to the search bar.

And to display the same results as the search bar, you would subscribe to the `searchResults` observable and display the search results it emits.

Comment: JB thank you so very much! your explanation was clear and concise and proved very helpful. I now have my search results populating in console.log successfully from my sidenav.component.ts. The piece I did not fully understand was needing to create a new Observable to "wiretap" the communication (your analogy was perfect BTW). But for my own understanding, since I am using a "Subject" am I technically creating a new "dataStream" to "wiretap" the communication... and subscribing to that? or is a Subject technically an Observable too? -Thank you again for your help on this-

Comment: Subject is an Observable. Not sure what you mean by "creating a new dataStream".

Comment: on some of the explanations I have researched on Observables they refer to a "datastream" ie keystrokes and then feeding that "stream" into an observable that can be "subscribed to". In the tour of Heroes this explanation uses the term stream as well.. it also clearly states a subject is an Observable also and I must have missed that completely... you helped me identify my confusion.  -A Subject is also an Observable. You can turn the stream of search terms into a stream of Hero arrays and assign the result to the heroes property.-